# How to properly use setTimeOut?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I've been trying to properly use `setTimeOut` but haven't been able to figure it out.

`Expected Output:`

if you click any button, a banner will slide into view, after 8 seconds it will disappear.

click anywhere else on the page and the banner disappear.

click the same button before the 8 seconds timer ends and a new 8 should start.

`Actual output:`

if you click any button a banner will slide into view, after 8 seconds it will disappear.

click anywhere on the page so the banner disappear.

click the same button before the 8 seconds timer ends, instead of starting a new 8-seconds the banner will finish off the remaining seconds of the first click then disappear.

Here is what I've tried and also a codesandbox:
[a link] https://codesandbox.io/s/n7zvwn11yj

```
const getGreetingBanner =(e)=>{
  let query = document.querySelector(e)
      query.style.right = '8px';

    let timer = setTimeout(() => {
        query.style.right = '-165px';
    }, 8000);

   clearTimeOut(timer)
}

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => { 
  let triggeredElement = e.target.className;
    if (triggeredElement === 'container') {
            document.querySelectorAll('.banishBanner').forEach(function(x) {
        x.style.right = '-180px';
      })
    }
})
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <button  onclick="getGreetingBanner('.thankyou')" type="button" class="accept">Accept</button>
    <button  onclick="getGreetingBanner('.comeBackSoon')" type="button" class="cancel">Cancel</button>
    <div class="banishBanner thankyou">Thank You!</div>
   <div class="banishBanner comeBackSoon">Come back soon.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must clear timeout when you clicking again on same button.

```
var timeout;
const getGreetingBanner =(e)=>{
  let query = document.querySelector(e)
      query.style.right = '8px';
    //clearing timeout
    clearTimeout( timeout );

    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        query.style.right = '-165px';
    }, 8000);
}
```

Comment: does the timeout variable need to be global?

Comment: @Vash it's better to assign it within a global scope so you can access it anywhere with in the page.